# Scaling-Master / Unable to perform initial IP allocation check

Tags: kubernetes, azure-container-service

I started from 3 master nodes and I increased it to 5. I am trying to add the new members to the existing cluster. My apiserver container stops working with the following error:

```
E1106 20:44:18.977854 1 cacher.go:274] unexpected ListAndWatch error: k8s.io/kubernetes/vendor/k8s.io/apiserver/pkg/storage/cacher.go:215: Failed to list *storage.StorageClass: client: etcd cluster is unavailable or misconfigured
I1106 20:44:19.043807 1 logs.go:41] http: TLS handshake error from 10.0.118.9:52142: EOF
I1106 20:44:19.072129 1 logs.go:41] http: TLS handshake error from 10.0.118.9:52148: EOF
I1106 20:44:19.084461 1 logs.go:41] http: TLS handshake error from 10.0.118.9:52150: EOF
F1106 20:44:19.103677 1 controller.go:128] Unable to perform initial IP allocation check: unable to refresh the service IP block: client: etcd cluster is unavailable or misconfigured
```

From the already working master nodes I can see the new member:

```
azureuser@k8s-master-50639053-0:~$ etcdctl member list
99673c60d6c07e0e: name=k8s-master-50639053-2 peerURLs=http://10.0.118.7:2380 clientURLs=
b130aa7583380f88: name=k8s-master-50639053-3 peerURLs=http://10.0.118.8:2380 clientURLs=
b4b196cc0c9fca4a: name=k8s-master-50639053-1 peerURLs=http://10.0.118.6:2380 clientURLs=
c264b3b67880db3f: name=k8s-master-50639053-0 peerURLs=http://10.0.118.5:2380 clientURLs=
e6e511de7d665829: name=k8s-master-50639053-4 peerURLs=http://10.0.118.9:2380 clientURLs=
```

If I check the cluster health I got:

```
azureuser@k8s-master-50639053-0:~$ etcdctl cluster-health
member 99673c60d6c07e0e is healthy: got healthy result from http://10.0.118.7:2379
member b4b196cc0c9fca4a is healthy: got healthy result from http://10.0.118.6:2379
member c264b3b67880db3f is healthy: got healthy result from http://10.0.118.5:2379
member fd36b7acc85d92b8 is unhealthy: got unhealthy result from http://10.0.118.9:2379
cluster is healthy
```

It works if I run in the new master node and stop the etcd service:

```
sudo etcd --listen-client-urls http://10.0.118.9:2379 --advertise-client-urls http://10.0.118.9:2379 --listen-peer-urls http://10.0.118.9:2380
```

Could someone help me?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update: According to [git](https://github.com/Azure/acs-engine/issues/1716) its due to certificates and its not currently supported by ACS-ENGINE.